# Как подключить Телеграм Бота к Яндекс.Кассе?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, платежи, яндекс-касса

Решили подключить прием платежей через Яндек Кассу с помощью бота. И столкнулись с такой проблемой:
во время тестов платеж проходит очень быстро, за секунды, а когда подключаешь магазин - юзер зависает в таймауте и платеж зачастую не отображается в магазине. Если у кого-то есть опыт подключения платежей через телеграм ботов, можете подсказать, в чем может быть ошибка?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.row(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Начать оплату', callback_data='start_payment'))
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=10Ez-WV5_55Kc2MoMPA88elkKtIBWRj6D')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нажмите, чтобы начать оплату:', reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data == 'start_payment')
def start_payment(call):
    tg_id = call.message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(tg_id,
                     ''' 
                     Use this test card number to pay for your Item: 
1111 1111 1111 1026
Expiration Date: 12/22
CVC: 000
                    '''
                     )

    bot.send_invoice(tg_id, title='Item for Sale',
                     description='Bla-Bla-Bla',
                     provider_token=live_payment_token, # ТЕСТОВЫЙ ТОКЕН (TEST) РАБОТАЕТ, А ВОТ С LIVE ПОСТОЯННО ГЛЮЧИТ
                     currency='RUB',
                     photo_url=None,
                     need_phone_number=False,
                     need_email=False,
                     is_flexible=False,  # True If you need to set up Shipping Fee
                     prices=[LabeledPrice(label='Item_Name', amount=250000)],
                     start_parameter='start_parameter',
                     invoice_payload='coupon')

@bot.pre_checkout_query_handler(func=lambda query: True)
def checkout(query):
    print(query)
        bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(query.id, ok=True)  

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['successful_payment'])
def got_payment(message):
    # print(message)
    tg_id = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(tg_id,'Ваш платеж успешно дошел, спасибо за оплату!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился сам по себе, нужно было дождаться подтверждения магазина от Яндекс.Касса, иначе LIVE токен не работает.